# php script.php printed the script, instead of executing it on linux?

Tags: php, linux

I was working on migrating a web server, and one of the back end script is not executing properly from cron. So I manually attempted to execute the php script, and instead of executing it, the scripted was printed to the console. The permission is set to 777.

```
[root@hostname]#    php script.php
<?
$log->LogStart();
.........
.....
......
?>
```

Comment: Use `<?php` instead of `<?`?

Comment: If you are using the `php` CLI command, the script doesn't need to be executable.  It could just be 0644.

Answer (score 2):

HamZa is spot on in his comment. Use the full open tag `<?php` in stead of the short open tag `<?`.

You have allowed for short open tags in your `php.ini`, but when calling php from the command line, that `php.ini` is not used. (You can point to that `php.ini` by supplying an parameter with your call.)

With the short open tags not allowed, php parses the `<?` as regular 'html', and echoes it out.